# Means to get IP and MAC information from a list of known Hostnames

Tags: linux

I have a list of hostnames for mixed Linux distros (some Solaris, some RedHat, some Ubuntu), I need to get the IP and MAC for any Ethernet devices on each distro.

I don't have root access to any of these servers, so I wrote a bash script on one that remotely runs on the others and returns IP and MAC parsed from output of ifconfig. Because this script uses an expect file to pass in my password, it takes a long time to execute and is not very elegant.

There has to be a better way to do this. I know of a few tools that can do it for me but unfortunately I can't install any additional packages as I don't have permissions to do so.

The output of `arp -a` gives exactly what I want, but the problem with this is some of these entries seem to have multiple IPs and hostnames binded to the same MAC address. So I get entries like:
    HOSTNAME-1 (IP-1) at SAME_MAC_ADDR [ether] on eth0
    HOSTNAME-2 (IP-2) at SAME_MAC_ADDR [ether] on eth0
    ?          (IP-2) at SAME_MAC_ADDR [ether] on eth0

Is there a way to firstly get all IPs and MAC addresses from the list of hostnames I have? I'm guessing arp is what I need here?

Secondly, is there a means to get all additional hostnames or IPs associated with each MAC address if there are duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arp command will show the list of MAC address and associated IP addresses of hosts known to the one you are connecting to.

ifconfig is the right tool to use (or "ip a" in some distros). Why don't you try to put a cron job in every machine to store the result of "ip a" or "ifconfig" into a tempfile and instead or executing the command in every remote host, you just donwload this file and parse in your local server?

If not, they only way to get accurate information of network adapters in a *IX box is to get into the host and ask for this info.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at doing a cron job on all of the systems, but instead ran a cronjob every few minutes on my main server that takes about 4-5 mins to gather the details from all other servers. Does what I needed!